# How to create paypal shipping label

Tags: paypal

I am using paypal wps on my site with shipping enabled, but i can not generate shipping label after payment completion.
i can generate shipping label through merchant account for customers but can not generate thorough customer account at time of checkout or after payment completion.
is there any method to generate shipping label after payment completion ?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, PayPal does not provide API's for generating shipping labels (or even working with tracking data after generating labels through the merchant account, which I've been begging for many years now).

You could do what you're trying to do, but you'll need to work directly with the shipping carrier API's.  They each have their own developer tools.

- [USPS Web Tools](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/welcome.htm)
- [FedEx Developer Resource Center](http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/)
- [UPS Developer Kit](https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit)

Alternatively, you could use a 3rd party API like [EasyPost](https://www.easypost.com) to integrate them all.